# Difference between 64 and 128 byte descriptors

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, descriptor

Recently I was trying to extract **descriptors** using KAZE and AKAZE functions in **OpenCV**. I saw that there are 2 types of descriptors: 64 byte and 128 byte.

My question is: What is the main difference between these 2 descriptors?

Comment: It should  depend only on the size of the neighborhood used to compute the descriptor. Bigger neighborhood means bigger (thus more informative) descriptor, but slower to compute.

Comment: Yeah. I also think in that way. But here is an interesting experiment I have done. For the same pair of picture the 64 byte version founds 277 matches, while using the 128 byte descriptor it founds 53 matches. And I can't understand why.

Comment: Those 53 are probably more accurate / reliable then your 277 matches..

Comment: Reasonable. Thank you. :)